# Hashing text file line by line

Tags: c, database, hash

I am trying to hash a text file that contains 19 lines of student personal information. There is a case based system that I can choose what action I want to do like Insert in Hash, Display, etc. The code simply won't read the text file I have provided and when I press Display as an action it will bring up nothing. The same thing will happen when I press the Insert choice, etc.

Comment: You are calling `Hash` on uninitialized pointer `int hashIndex = Hash(AM, 19);` did you mean to call `int hashIndex = Hash(node.AM, 19);`?

Comment: @kiran Biradar  I wrote my code based on this post , so I think that answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56226055/hashingwith-chains-a-student-database-bit-folding-additive-hashing

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: It is a good idea to provide a brief, but complete, compilable example showing specific issues you are having.  It this case, you have provided way too much poorly formatted code (that has been edited since), but it does not contain a `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` function, so it will not compile.  Please edit your post to include how you have written your main function.

Comment: For me `(line[len - 1] != '\n')` must be `(line[len - 1] == '\n')`, and you have several other problems, see my answer

Comment: @ryyker I have edited in my main function

Comment: @vaskar you also have problems in your _main_, I edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code simply won't read the text file I have provided

your problem probably comes from :

> ```
>    char line[4096];
>    while (fgets(line, sizeof line,fp)) 
>    {
>        size_t len = strlen(line);
>        if (len && (line[len - 1] != '\n'))
> ```

because of `(line[len - 1] != '\n')` which is probably never true because *fgets* is able to read a large line and considering the *fscanf* after the lines contains only few data.

Why do you want to work on */* incomplete line */*  ?

Work on complete lines with the test

```
if (len && (line[len - 1] == '\n'))
```

You also have an unexpected *return* in

> ```
>  if (!hashTable[hashIndex].head) 
>  {
>    hashTable[hashIndex].head = newNode;
>    hashTable[hashIndex].count = 1;
>    return;
>  }
> ```

because of it you cannot read more than one answer, put the lines after in an `else { ... }`

Note also your code supposes the user ask *only one times* to insert, if he does several times you will add several times the same elements.

After you read a line you again read in the file doing

> ```
>  fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %d",node.AM, node.first_name, node.last_name, &node.grade);
> ```

so you only save the data from half the lines, you wanted to do

```
sscanf(line,"%s %s %s %d",node.AM, node.first_name, node.last_name, &node.grade);
```

---

You have additional problems

In *Hash* you suppose the identifier has at least 7 characters, if this is not the case you read out of the name (after the null character) with an undefined behavior

Do something like :

```
int Hash(char *AM, int n)
{    
  int i;
  int hashIndex = 0;

  for (i=0; (i< 8) && (AM[i] != 0); i++)
  {
    hashIndex += AM[i];
  }

  return hashIndex % n;
}
```

However your hash is very poor, there are much better ways to hash a string

In

> ```
>         fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %d",node.AM, node.first_name, node.last_name, &node.grade);
> ```

you use the format *%d* for an *int* but `node.grade` is a *float*, replace *%d* by *%f* and also check *fscanf* returns 4

I also encourage you to limit the size of the read string to not take the risk to write out of the fields, so (in fact the *fscanf* has to be replaced by a *sscanf*)

```
fscanf(fp,"%99s %99s %99s %f", ...)
```

In

> ```
> printf("Student ID  : %d\n", myNode->AM);
> ```

and

> ```
> printf("%-12d", myNode->AM);
> ```

you use the format *%d* for an *int* but you give a `char*`

Replace *d* by *s* or change the type of *AM* (and how to read and use it elsewhere of course)

The return at the end of *insertToHash* is useless, there are some other useless *return* else where

In

> ```
> printf("grade      : %d\n", myNode->grade);
> ```

and

> ```
> printf("%d\n", myNode->grade);
> ```

you use the format *%d* for an *int* but you give a double

Replace *%d* by *%lf* or *%lg* etc

In

> ```
> int hashIndex = Hash(AM, 19);
> ```

*AM* is not initialized, the behavior is undefined

You wanted

```
int hashIndex = Hash(node.AM, 19);
```

In

> ```
> struct node *newnode = createNode(AM, first_name, last_name, grade);
> ```

`AM` and `first_name` and `last_name` and `grade` are not initialized, the behavior is undefined

You wanted

```
struct node *newnode = createNode(node.AM, node.first_name, node.last_name, node.grade);
```

and remove the useless variables `hashIndex, grade, last_name, first_name, AM`

In *deleteFromHash*  and *searchInHash* the test

> ```
>  if (myNode->AM == AM)
> ```

is wrong because you compare pointers, you wanted

```
if (!strcmp(myNode->AM, AM))
```

---

In

> ```
> struct node 
> {
>   float grade;
>   char AM[100];
>   char first_name[100];
>   char last_name[100];
>   struct node *next;
> }node;
> ```

the same name is used for the struct and the global variable, this is not a good idea.

Also the global variable *node* is only used in *insertToHash*, so you do not need it, remove the global variable and add a local variable into *insertToHash*.

---

After you edit adding *main*

> ```
> scanf("%d", &AM);
> ```

must be (2 times)

```
scanf("%99s", AM);
```

Your variables `first_name, last_name` and `grade` are unused

---

The code taking into account all my remarks is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct hash *hashTable = NULL;
int eleCount = 0;

struct Node 
{
  float grade;
  char AM[100];
  char first_name[100];
  char last_name[100];
  struct Node *next;
};

struct hash 
{
struct Node *head;
int count;
};

struct Node * createNode(char *AM, char *first_name, char *last_name, float grade) 
{
  struct Node *newNode;

  newNode = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  strcpy(newNode->AM, AM);
  strcpy(newNode->last_name, last_name);
  strcpy(newNode->first_name, first_name);
  newNode->grade = grade;
  newNode->next = NULL;
  return newNode;
}

int Hash(char *AM, int n)
{    
  int i;
  int hashIndex = 0;

  for (i=0; (i< 8) && (AM[i] != 0); i++)
  {
    hashIndex += AM[i];
  }

  return hashIndex % n;
}

void insertToHash() 
{
  struct Node node;

  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen ("Foitites-Vathmologio-DS.txt","rb");

  if (fp == NULL) 
  { 
    fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file");  
    return;
  } 

  char line[4096];

  while (fgets(line, sizeof line,fp)) {
    size_t len = strlen(line);
    if (len && (line[len - 1] == '\n')) {
      /* complete line */
      if (sscanf(line,"%99s %99s %99s %f",node.AM, node.first_name, node.last_name, &node.grade) != 4) {
    puts("invalid file");
    return;
      }

      int hashIndex = Hash(node.AM, 19);

      struct Node *newNode = createNode(node.AM, node.first_name, node.last_name, node.grade);
      /* head of list for the bucket with index "hashIndex" */

      if (!hashTable[hashIndex].head) 
      {
        hashTable[hashIndex].head = newNode;
        hashTable[hashIndex].count = 1;
      }
      else {
        /* adding new Node to the list */
        newNode->next = (hashTable[hashIndex].head);
        /*
           * update the head of the list and no of
           * Nodes in the current bucket
        */
        hashTable[hashIndex].head = newNode;
        hashTable[hashIndex].count++;
      }
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
  printf("Done! \n");
}

void deleteFromHash(char *AM) 
{
  /* find the bucket using hash index */
  int hashIndex = Hash(AM, 19);
  int flag = 0;

  struct Node *temp, *myNode;
  /* get the list head from current bucket */

  myNode = hashTable[hashIndex].head;

  if (!myNode) {
    printf("Given data is not present in hash Table!!\n");

    return;
  }

  temp = myNode;
  while (myNode != NULL) {
    /* delete the Node with given AM */
    if (!strcmp(myNode->AM, AM)) {
      flag = 1;
      if (myNode == hashTable[hashIndex].head)
        hashTable[hashIndex].head = myNode->next;
      else
        temp->next = myNode->next;

      hashTable[hashIndex].count--;
      free(myNode);
      break;
    }

    temp = myNode;
    myNode = myNode->next;
  }
  if (flag)
    printf("Data deleted successfully from Hash Table\n");
  else
    printf("Given data is not present in hash Table!!!!\n");
}

void searchInHash(char *AM) {
  int hashIndex = Hash(AM, 19);
  int flag = 0;
  struct Node *myNode;        myNode = hashTable[hashIndex].head;
  if (!myNode) {
    printf("Search element unavailable in hash table\n");
    return;
  }
  while (myNode != NULL) {
    if (!strcmp(myNode->AM, AM)) {
      printf("Student ID  : %s\n", myNode->AM);
      printf("First Name     : %s\n", myNode->first_name);
      printf("Last Name     : %s\n", myNode->last_name);
      printf("grade      : %lg\n", myNode->grade);
      flag = 1;
      break;
    }
    myNode = myNode->next;
  }
  if (!flag)
    printf("Search element unavailable in hash table\n");
}

void display() {
  struct Node *myNode;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < eleCount; i++) {
    if (hashTable[i].count == 0)
      continue;
    myNode = hashTable[i].head;
    if (!myNode)
      continue;
    printf("\nData at index %d in Hash Table:\n", i);
    printf("Student ID    First Name    Last Name      Grade   \n");
    printf("--------------------------------\n");
    while (myNode != NULL) {
      printf("%-12s", myNode->AM);
      printf("%-15s", myNode->first_name);
      printf("%-15s", myNode->last_name);
      printf("%lg\n", myNode->grade);
      myNode = myNode->next;
    }
  }
}

int main() 
{
  int n=19, ch;
  char AM[100];
  int insertDone = 0;

  eleCount = n;
  /* create hash table with "n" no of buckets */
  hashTable = (struct hash *) calloc(n, sizeof(struct hash));
  while (1) {
    printf("\n1. Insertion\t2. Deletion\n");
    printf("3. Searching\t4. Display\n5. Exit\n");
    printf("Enter your choice:");
    scanf("%d", &ch);


    switch (ch) {
    case 1: 
      if (insertDone)
        puts("Inserton was already done");
      else {
    /*inserting new Node to hash table */
        insertToHash();
        insertDone = 1;
      }
      break;

    case 2: 
      printf("Enter the AM to perform deletion:");
      scanf("%99s", AM);
      /* delete Node with "AM" from hash table */
      deleteFromHash(AM);
      break;

    case 3: 
      printf("Enter the AM to search:");
      scanf("%99s", AM);
      searchInHash(AM);
      break;
    case 4: 
      display();
      break;
    case 5: 
      exit(0);
    default: 
      printf("U have entered wrong option!!\n");
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat Foitites-Vathmologio-DS.txt
123 aze qsd 1.23
456 iop jkl 4.56
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

1. Insertion    2. Deletion
3. Searching    4. Display
5. Exit
Enter your choice:4

1. Insertion    2. Deletion
3. Searching    4. Display
5. Exit
Enter your choice:1
Done! 

1. Insertion    2. Deletion
3. Searching    4. Display
5. Exit
Enter your choice:4

Data at index 7 in Hash Table:
Student ID    First Name    Last Name      Grade   
--------------------------------
456         iop            jkl            4.56

Data at index 17 in Hash Table:
Student ID    First Name    Last Name      Grade   
--------------------------------
123         aze            qsd            1.23

1. Insertion    2. Deletion
3. Searching    4. Display
5. Exit
Enter your choice:1
Inserton was already done

1. Insertion    2. Deletion
3. Searching    4. Display
5. Exit
Enter your choice:3
Enter the AM to search:123
Student ID  : 123
First Name     : aze
Last Name     : qsd
grade      : 1.23

1. Insertion    2. Deletion
3. Searching    4. Display
5. Exit
Enter your choice:3
Enter the AM to search:1234
Search element unavailable in hash table

1. Insertion    2. Deletion
3. Searching    4. Display
5. Exit
Enter your choice:2
Enter the AM to perform deletion:1
Given data is not present in hash Table!!

1. Insertion    2. Deletion
3. Searching    4. Display
5. Exit
Enter your choice:2
Enter the AM to perform deletion:123
Data deleted successfully from Hash Table

1. Insertion    2. Deletion
3. Searching    4. Display
5. Exit
Enter your choice:4

Data at index 7 in Hash Table:
Student ID    First Name    Last Name      Grade   
--------------------------------
456         iop            jkl            4.56

1. Insertion    2. Deletion
3. Searching    4. Display
5. Exit
Enter your choice:2
Enter the AM to perform deletion:456
Data deleted successfully from Hash Table

1. Insertion    2. Deletion
3. Searching    4. Display
5. Exit
Enter your choice:4

1. Insertion    2. Deletion
3. Searching    4. Display
5. Exit
Enter your choice:5
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: I think we are making some progress here! Before I make the changes to the main funtion and specifically in the scaf("%d", &AM) , when I selected the Display case It would display just the first line of my file but after the change you proposed I get return ld1 exit status

Comment: @vaskar I continue to correct your code and currently the display produces the entries I put in the file

Comment: I have edited in mu code with the corrections you have provided allong with the contents and form of my .txt file and now , when I choose Display it shows two or three students at the same time as if they are in the same node

Comment: @vaskar I continue to edit my answer to correct your code, please wait I finish, I will warn you and also put the full corrected code

Comment: @vaskar done, I put the full corrected code and an example of execution, but read all my answer to understand the changes

Comment: I implemented your code with my text file and although it works as you describe when I choose the Display option, I get some nodes containing one entry and some 2-3. I have put the results in my original post that I edited! Finally, I have already upvoted your answer which was indeed immensely helpful but due to my reputation, it won't count :( I have marked your question as accepted!

Comment: Plus one for your extensive effort alone.

Comment: @bruno I have, yes. Thanks for your help!